# I got an error Attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a python application and trying to manage the code in a structure.

The directory structure that I have is something like the following:-

```
package/
   A/
     __init__.py
     base.py
   B/
     __init__.py
     base.py
app.py
__init__.py
```

so I have a line in A/**init**.py that says

```
from .base import *
```

No problem there, but when I put the same line in B/**init**.py

```
from .base import *
```

I get an error

```
E0402: Attempted relative import beyond top-level package.
```

Isn't the two supposed to be identical? what exactly am I doing wrong here?

I am using Python 3.6, the way I ran the application is from the terminal with

```
> python app.py
```

Thanks

UPDATE:
Sorry, The error is from somewhere else.

In A/base.py i have

```
class ClassA():
  ...
```

In B/base.py I have

```
from ..A import ClassA

class ClassB(ClassA):
  ...
```

The error came from the import statement in B/base.py

```
from ..A import ClassA
```

UPDATE #2
@JOHN_16 app.py is as follows:-

```
from A import ClassA
from B import ClassB

if __name__ == "__main__":
  ...
```

Also updated directory to include empty **init**.py as suggested.

Comment: Think about the order in which Python processes the module declarations

Comment: What is content of app.py ?

Comment: @JOHN_16 refer to UPDATE #2 thx. any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is occurred because you have two packages: *A* and *B*. Package *B* can't get access to content of package *A* via relative import because it cant move outside top-level package. In you case both packages are top-level.

You need reorganize you project, for example like that

```
.
├── TL
│   ├── A
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── base.py
│   ├── B
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── base.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── app.py
```

and change content pf you `app.py` to use package TL:

```
from TL.A import ClassA
from TL.B import ClassB

if __name__ == "__main__":
```

Comment: I'll mark this as the correct answer. I managed to get it working in this structure that you suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My problem was forgetting `__init__.py` in my top level directory. This allowed me to use relative imports for folders in that directory.